# Google API Request stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an API that I use to get the events from multiple accounts. Recently the API stopped working and I am not able to figure out why.

Here is an example of my request: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/pub500.mankato%40gmail.com/events?key=myKey

The call returns a Google_Service_Exception - (400) Bad Request

Comment: Your key is invalid

Comment: { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" }

Comment: That is not the key I am using.

Comment: Can you then post what you get back? The whole response?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/pub500.mankato%40gmail.com/events?key=myKey: (400) Bad Request' in /home/katotest/public_html/crons/google-api-php-client-1.1.6/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110

Comment: My guess is to check params and the key that you are sending. Check also you use the right version api

Comment: $params = array(
        'singleEvents' => true,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'timeMin' => date(DateTime::ATOM)
    );

Comment: Do you have the ability to get only the api reaponse with your valod key? (Google dev tools or Postman)

Comment: I created a new API key and now I get this error. "(403) The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."

Comment: it means you have to specify an refer in your API call or go to your API console (where you created the new KEY) and remove the "referer restriction"

Comment: Ok, that worked, thank you.

Comment: @Michael, if you consider these comments have been useful for answering the question, would you mind posting an answer about what you have done with NickOs in the comments? Thank you.

Comment: @RodrigoC. I did it :)

Answer (score 1):

From you question, I take it that you are managing authentication for calling APIs. Based on the information provided by Michael, I think you will find this GCP documentation for using API keys helpful:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions

Comment: Thanks for posting this potentially helpful resource. While it may answer the question, [it is necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and ideally to provide the link for reference. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question (is|was) to validate the error response message from the API and *read it carefully*. I also recommend rechecking API settings(Console), the API call and to check every single step if its use in any kind of framework. (Test against the API)

```
Google_Service_Exception - (400) Bad Request
```

seems to be invalid API credentials (API key)

**Update** after creating `new API key`:

```
"(403) The request did not specify any referer. 
 Please ensure that the client is sending referer 
 or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
```

That means you have to specify a referer in your API call or go to your API console (where you created the new KEY) and remove the "referer restriction"